# If we are certain there is a God then why is it called a 'faith'?

Tags: faith

If we declare there is a God and do not deny him then why do we call it a 'faith'?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your question, while an interesting one, is not a good fir for this particular site as it will attract answers that will be primarily-opinion-based rather than relating to specific Christian doctrines. Please take the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and  check out [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines?s=1|1.8881) if you'd like more of an idea of the type of questions  that can work well here.

Answer (score 2):

Hebrews tells us that,

> “...*faith is confidence in what we hope for and assurance about
>   **what we do not see.***” (11:1 NIV)

As well as,

> “...*without faith it is impossible to please God, because anyone who
>   comes to him **must believe that he exists** and that he rewards those
>   who earnestly seek him.*” (11:6‬ ‭NIV‬‬)

Faith pertains to our belief in the existence of God by default. With the added parameters of the cross, our faith rests in the Fathers agreement with the Son in providing a sufficient atoning sacrifice in Jesus' death whereby God's wrath is fully appeased. Faith is believing that Jesus is a sufficient savior on a spiritual level; bringing us into a restored relationship with God and not just a historical martyr who died for what he believed in.

Paul states this clearly in his letter to the Romans,

> “*This righteousness is given through faith in Jesus Christ to all who
>   believe... for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God, and
>   all are justified freely by his grace through the redemption that came
>   by Christ Jesus. **God presented Christ as a sacrifice of atonement,
>   through the shedding of his blood—to be received by faith**. He did
>   this to demonstrate his righteousness, because in his forbearance he
>   had left the sins committed beforehand unpunished— he did it to
>   demonstrate his righteousness at the present time, so as to be just
>   and the one who justifies those who have faith in Jesus*.” (3:22-26‬ ‭NIV)‬‬

It was lengthy, but I hope that helps. :)

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  Unfortunately, the question you've answered is not one that is good for our format, since it invites answers from many different perspectives.  As a result, it has been closed. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: But why must we believe that God exists? Should his existence not be self-evident and without the required component of faith?